# Many to many relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a many to many relationship between two models in Rails 3.2.11.

A User can be associated with many Incidents and vice versa.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

  has_many :incident_participants, foreign_key: "participant_id"
  has_many :participated_incidents, through: :incident_participants

end


class Incident < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

  has_many :incident_participants, foreign_key: "participated_incident_id"
  has_many :participants, through: :incident_participants

end
```

The join table:

```
class IncidentParticipant < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

  t.belongs_to :participant, class_name: "User"
  t.belongs_to :participated_incident, class_name: "Incident"
end
```

Table for IncidentParticipants

```
  create_table "incident_participants", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "participant_id"
    t.integer  "participated_incident_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",               :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",               :null => false
  end
```

So, why doesn't rails get this relationship? When I try to do @incident.participants in my view I get this error:

> "Could not find the source association(s) :participant or
>   :participants in model IncidentParticipant. Try 'has_many
>   :participants, :through => :incident_participants, :source => '.
>   Is it one of ?"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking out the `t.belongs_to` and replace with `belongs_to`.

Comment: haha no problem. I guess t exists as a method, because you didn't get a nomethoderror for nil class, otherwise you probably would have caught it. :)

Answer (score 0):

To create a many to many association you should consider creating an association table. That is to say you will have two 1-M relationships that point to a sort interim table. For instance:

In your first model:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :example2
end
```

In your second model:

```
class Example2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :example
end
```

Then you need to write a migration to link the two tables together:

```
class CreateTableExamplesExamples2 < ActiveRecord::Migration
  create_table :examples_examples2 do |t|
    t.integer :example_id
    t.integer :example2_id
  end
end
```

Then just let rails magic work. Check out the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) for more information.